# Asp.net Gridview error: Operator '-' is not defined for types 'Object' and 'Date'

Tags: asp.net, datetime, gridview

I used this code: `(Eval("RegDtTime")-DateTime.Now` to calculate the difference between Registered DateTime (is in a database) and `DateTime.now` in a `gridview`,  But get this error: `operator '-' is not defined for types 'Object' and 'Date'`. So what should I use instead?

Comment: Check http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?356101-RESOLVED-Operator-is-not-defined-for-types-Date-and-Integer

Comment: What do you need? Difference in days? months? timespan?

Comment: This is right now. But I don't know how to get the minutes. `(Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("LastDateTime"))- (DateTime.Now))`

Comment: You can use `(Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("LastDateTime"))- (DateTime.Now)).TotalMinutes`

Comment: try this <%# (Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("LastDateTime"))- (DateTime.Now)).ToString("{0:d/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt}") %>

Comment: Yes thank you so much. I used `convert.toint32((Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("LastDateTime"))- (DateTime.Now)).TotalMinutes)` perhaps it is better i find another way to delet floating point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below `Eval Object`

```
<%# System.Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("RegDtTime"))%>
```

So that your template will be

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width = "100px"  HeaderText = "DATE" >
   <ItemTemplate >
       <%# (System.Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("Date")) - (DateTime.Now)) %>
   </ItemTemplate>       
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of coding the logic in aspx files, you can define a method in code behind and call that from GridView.

This is my `GridView` in aspx.

```
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" 
                  Text='<%# GetCalculatedDateTime(Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("RegDtTime"))) %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

This is my Entity or Model.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public DateTime RegDtTime { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the code behind for ASPX.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            var lst = new List<MyClass>();
            lst.Add(new MyClass { RegDtTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-5) });
            lst.Add(new MyClass { RegDtTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(6) });
            lst.Add(new MyClass { RegDtTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5) });
            lst.Add(new MyClass { RegDtTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-9) });
            lst.Add(new MyClass { RegDtTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7) });

            GridView1.DataSource = lst;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
 }

 public static string GetCalculatedDateTime(DateTime dt)
 {
     var result = dt - DateTime.Now;
     return result.ToString();
 }
```

You can write the required logic in `GetCalculatedDateTime` method.

Comment: this solved my problem: `convert.toint32((Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("LastDateTime"))- (DateTime.Now)).TotalMinutes)`